# KQL :: Find Azure SQL Databases where name like "_old"

Tags: azure, kql, azure-resource-graph

I'm new to KQL and I'm trying to list all Azure SQL Databases with the word "_old" in their name.

My protoquery is this and it works:

```
// Find "_old" Databases
Resources
| where type =~ 'microsoft.sql/servers/databases'
| where *  contains  "old"
| project  resourceName = name,type,sku.name,sku.tier,tags.createdBy,tags.customerCode,tags.managedBy, resourceGroup, subscriptionId, location
```

But here the `WHERE` clause is bombing everywhere across all columns.

Is there a more fashionable way to search into Azure ideally with more words like:

- _old
- .old
- _test
- .test
- _dev
- .dev

I have to clean up unused resources and I have to search per resource name.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the professional term "bombing everywhere across all columns". What exactly is the issue / what exactly are you looking for?

Comment: How about `where name  contains  "old"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- AS of today, Azure Resource Graph supports a quite limited subset of KQL. E.g. `has_any` is currently not supported.
- If needed, you can uncomment the commented line to improve performance.

---

```
Resources
| where type == 'microsoft.sql/servers/databases'
// | where name has_cs "old" or name has_cs "dev" or name has_cs "test"
| parse-where kind=regex name with ".*[._]" suffix
| where suffix in ("old", "dev", "test")
```

Comment: Ah, regex on KQL, I'm definitely go to use that. Thank you @David

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @PeterBonz, the `name` is what I was missing.

My code now works this way:

```
// Find Unused Virtual Machines
Resources
| where type has "microsoft.compute/virtualmachines"
| where name contains "old"
    or name contains "dev"
    or name contains "test"
| project resourceName = name,type,sku.name,sku.tier,tags.createdBy,tags.customerCode,tags.managedBy, resourceGroup, subscriptionId, location
```

I also found the clause `has_any` but I couldn't make it work:

```
let ComputerTerms = pack_array('old', 'dev', 'test');
// Find Unused Virtual Machines
Resources
| where type has "microsoft.compute/virtualmachines"
| where name has_any (ComputerTerms) 
| project resourceName = name,type,sku.name,sku.tier,tags.createdBy,tags.customerCode,tags.managedBy, resourceGroup, subscriptionId, location
```

Comment: As I wrote in my answer, "AS of today, Azure Resource Graph supports a quite limited subset of KQL. E.g. `has_any` is currently not supported"

Comment: I don't get the saying: "My code now works this way". You already got better options, that actually answer your request (looking for suffixes).

Comment: My problem was that my code was using * and therefore was searching for the word in all columns. I now can target the column "name" and this was the goal

Comment: It seems you were also looking for suffixes

Comment: Sorry @DavidדודוMarkovitz, my question was misleading. It's true that I was looking for suffix but the word sometimes is also inside the name